# Updating the lastModifiedTime of a file with Java on Windows fails when the filename includes non-ASCII characters

Tags: java, windows, character-encoding

I have a Java program that's attempting to modify the last modified time of a file:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Calendar.Builder;

public class UpdateMtime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        String fileName = args[0];
        try {
            File fileToUpdate = new File(fileName);
            Builder calBuilder = new Builder();
            calBuilder.setDate(2002, 10, 01);
            if(fileToUpdate.setLastModified(calBuilder.build().getTimeInMillis())) {
                System.out.println("Mtime update successful");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Mtime update unsuccessful");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }
}
```

On Windows, running `java UpdateMtime "test.txt"` in PowerShell 7.3 returns `Mtime update successful`, and I can see the file's last modified time is updated to `11/01/2022 12:00AM`.

However, running `java UpdateMtime "тестовый файл.txt"` returns `Mtime update unsuccessful`, and the file's last modified time is not updated.

Why isn't Java able to update the last modified time of a filename that has non-ASCII characters on Windows? I tried this same example on Linux, and the program was able to successfully update the last modified time on both files.

Comment: Are you sure it actually finds the file under Windows?  Does `fileToUpdate.exists()` return true?  If not, I would start by comparing the character sets of the OS and the java runtime.  Does the `String` containing the file name use the same character set as the file system?

Comment: Add `System.out.println("native.encoding="+System.getProperty("native.encoding"));`  `System.out.println("file.encoding="+System.getProperty("file.encoding"));` `System.out.println("sun.jnu.encoding="+System.getProperty("sun.jnu.encoding"));` to dump Windows Settigs.

Comment: @schtever You're right, it's *not* finding the file. `fileToUpdate.exists()` returns false.

Comment: @life888888 I get:

`native.encoding=Cp1252`

`file.encoding=Cp1252`

`sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252`

Comment: The problem is that I'm not sure how I'm supposed to re-encode `"тестовый файл.txt"` into `Cp1252` so that I can have the encodings match.

Comment: Try `String fileName = "\u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043E\u0432\u044B\u0439\u0020\u0444\u0430\u0439\u043B\u002E\u0074\u0078\u0074";` Needless to say, those Cyrillic characters are not supported under Cp1252 but if you're able to physically provide them as a program parameter, you could try running with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` but that might not work. Worth trying

Comment: After doing a lot of investigation, I found out that the encoding assumed for command line arguments is set by `sun.jnu.encoding`, not `file.encoding`. Unfortunately, on Windows, it doesn't seem like there's a way to set that value, as it's based on a hardcoded lookup against the system locale, which I don't want to mess with. What I ended up doing was refactoring the program to read its data from standard input, which allowed me to set the encoding with `-Dfile.encoding`.

Comment: *...refactoring the program to read its data from standard input...* Where was it getting its data from before?

Comment: It was getting the file names from `argv`. I refactored the program so it would read the file names from `stdin`, newline separated, and wrote a wrapper script that would take `argv` and pipe it into `stdin`.